# How do I center an image anchor in google maps api V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, anchor, center

I'm trying to center the anchor of an icon in the google maps api [here](http://www.projectstratos.com/map.php) but when I try to the explosion image disapears.

This code works fine but the anchor is at the bottom center of the image:

```
  var image_explode = 'images/map/explode.png';
  var explode_longlat = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431);
  var explode = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: explode_longlat,
      map: map,
      icon: image_explode
  });
```

I tried making the anchor centered using this code but it dissapears:

```
  var image_explode = new google.maps.MarkerImage("projectstratos.com/images/map/explode.png",new google.maps.Size(20,20),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(10,10));
  var explode_longlat = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431);
  var explode = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: explode_longlat,
      map: map,
      icon: image_explode
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the scheme (http://) in your URL if you are going to include the hostname:

```
  var explode_image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://projectstratos.com/images/map/explode.png", new google.maps.Size(20,20), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(10,10));
  var explode_longlat = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431);
  var explode = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: explode_longlat,
      map: map,
      icon: explode_image
  });
```

Alternatively, leave the hostname (projectstratos.com) off.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Could you tell me what you did that I was doing wrong?